# Salesforce custom object with custom field and standard field

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have one custom object 'Territory__c' which have standard Field "Name" and custom field "Territory_Ex_ID__c". So what would be SOQL whole data. Suppose the user list I want to fetch with this detail included.

I am new to salesforce, so please help me with scenario.

Comment: What does "SOQL whole data" mean? How are Users involved here?

Answer (score 0):

for fetching the field you just have to use there API names like in your example like

```
Select Name, Territory_Ex_ID__c from Territory__c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Territory__c> list = [Select Name, Territory_Ex_ID__c from Territory__c];
```

Comment: There is one thing if you want to link this with user you need to have a Lookup to user on Territory object and by Quering.List<Territory__c> list = [Select Name, Territory_Ex_ID__c from Territory__c where user = 'userid'];

Comment: I've meant to explain it in your answer... You can edit it anytime!